# PHP: MySQL Object not accessible by Child Class

Tags: php, mysql, class

With the function `chief` I am trying to initiate a mysql connection that will be used globally by multiple classes/functions.

When I extend this class to the `session` class the mysql object `$db` is not accessible by the child class.

```
class chief {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {

        $this->db=new stdClass();

        $this->db=new mysqli('', '', '', '');
    }

}

class session extends chief {
    public function __construct($address=null) {

        var_dump($this->db);
    }
}
```

Print results:

```
chief Object
(
    [db:protected] => mysqli Object
        (
            [affected_rows] => 0
            [client_info] => mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
            [client_version] => 50012
            [connect_errno] => 0
            [connect_error] => 
            [errno] => 0
            [error] => 
            [error_list] => Array
                (
                )

            [field_count] => 0
            [host_info] => 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
            [info] => 
            [insert_id] => 0
            [server_info] => 5.5.60-MariaDB
            [server_version] => 50560
            [stat] => Uptime: 1845718  Threads: 2  Questions: 210730  Slow queries: 0  Opens: 587  Flush tables: 2  Open tables: 396  Queries per second avg: 0.114
            [sqlstate] => 00000
            [protocol_version] => 10
            [thread_id] => 6008
            [warning_count] => 0
        )

)

session Object
(
    [storage:session:private] => 
    [db:protected] => 
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by inaccessible? Looks to me you're far dumping the object, aren't you?

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the parent constructor before:

```
class session extends chief {
    public function __construct($address=null) {
        parent::__construct(); // <--- HERE
        var_dump($this->db);
    }
}
```

From the docs:

> Note: Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class defines a constructor. In order to run a parent constructor, a call to parent::__construct() within the child constructor is required. If the child does not define a constructor then it may be inherited from the parent class just like a normal class method (if it was not declared as private).

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php